# Boxcryptor stopped working, how do I access the encrypted files on OnDrive, Dropbox, Google Drive?

Tags: encryption, dropbox, onedrive, google-drive, cloud

I have been using Boxcryptor for client side encryption of files stored in the cloud for a few years now.

They have been bought up by dropbox and the software stopped working today.

How do I access my encrypted files?

On their home page they recommend copying the files to an unencrypted location but I did not do that before the software stopped working

Answer (score 1):

If you had a free account, it's already too late - everything has been deleted.

If you had a paid account, you should still be able to

1. log in at their site https://www.boxcryptor.com/app/
2. export your key as a *.bckey file

Using this file and your boxcryptor password you can still decrypt your file

on Windows:

1. start the boxcryptor app, but do no log in
2. instead click the three dots in the upper right corner, and chose "local account"
3. drag and drop your *.bckey file into the app
4. type in your password

now the app is running as before, and decrypting your cloud files and
serving them as a virtual drive.  You can keep using it, or just
copy the files over to another storage location.

On MacOS:

1. double click the *.bckey file  in finder - this will start the app
2. type in your password

now the app is running as before, and decrypting your cloud files and
mounting them as /Users/USERNAME/Library/CloudStorage/ You can keep using the app, or just
copy the files over to another storage location.